# Docker build and docker-compose build with user namespace mapping

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have enabled user namespace mapping in docker and building an image using docker build works but when I use docker-compose for the image it fails with below message. What can be the reason for it?

```
db@vagrant:~/docker$ docker-compose up --build

Building db
Step 1/3 : FROM alpine:latest
 ---> e7d92cdc71fe
Step 2/3 : WORKDIR /app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 1491149423a1
Step 3/3 : COPY 1.txt .
ERROR: Service 'db' failed to build: failed to copy files: failed to copy file: Container ID 65536 cannot be mapped to a host ID
```

My user id is generated by some setup scripts which results in UID with larger than 65535 value.

```
db@vagrant:~/docker$ id
uid=65536(db) gid=1000(db) groups=1000(db),27(sudo),998(docker)

Docker configuration for namespace mapping

db@vagrant:~/docker$ cat /etc/docker/daemon.json
{
  "userns-remap": "db"
}

db@vagrant:~/docker$ cat /etc/subuid /etc/subgid
db:100000:65536
db:100000:65536
```

Dockerfile contents(1.txt is empty file)

```
db@vagrant:~/docker$ cat Dockerfile
FROM alpine:latest
WORKDIR /app
COPY 1.txt .
```

docker-compose.yml file contents

```
db@vagrant:~/docker$ cat docker-compose.yml
version: "2"
services:
   db:
     build:
       context: .
       dockerfile: Dockerfile
     image: sirishkumar/test
```

Output of docker build command

```
db@vagrant:~/docker$ docker build -t sirishkumar/test .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  3.584kB
Step 1/3 : FROM alpine:latest
latest: Pulling from library/alpine
c9b1b535fdd9: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:ab00606a42621fb68f2ed6ad3c88be54397f981a7b70a79db3d1172b11c4367d
Status: Downloaded newer image for alpine:latest
 ---> e7d92cdc71fe
Step 2/3 : WORKDIR /app
 ---> Running in 55f092b96268
Removing intermediate container 55f092b96268
 ---> 8af079e6a478
Step 3/3 : COPY 1.txt .
 ---> b3c14a691102
Successfully built b3c14a691102
Successfully tagged sirishkumar/test:latest
```

Output of docker-compose

```
db@vagrant:~/docker$ docker-compose up --build
Creating network "docker_default" with the default driver
Building db
Step 1/3 : FROM alpine:latest
latest: Pulling from library/alpine
c9b1b535fdd9: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:ab00606a42621fb68f2ed6ad3c88be54397f981a7b70a79db3d1172b11c4367d
Status: Downloaded newer image for alpine:latest
 ---> e7d92cdc71fe
Step 2/3 : WORKDIR /app
 ---> Running in fe39955aed1a
Removing intermediate container fe39955aed1a
 ---> fb23b8888f4a
Step 3/3 : COPY 1.txt .
ERROR: Service 'db' failed to build: failed to copy files: failed to copy file: Container ID 65536 cannot be mapped to a host ID
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a range of 65,536 user id's to map into your docker user namespace:

```
db@vagrant:~/docker$ cat /etc/subuid /etc/subgid
db:100000:65536
db:100000:65536
```

And then you're telling docker to copy a file into the container owned by an ID outside of that range (user ID's start at 0):

```
db@vagrant:~/docker$ id
uid=65536(db) gid=1000(db) groups=1000(db),27(sudo),998(docker)
```

You need to set your user id on the host to be within the host user id range (less than 65536).

Comment: I have the same understanding, but why docker build works but not docker-compose up --build?

Comment: @Poorna there are a lot of variables there, including versions, buildkit, and each implicitly goes through different workflows by default, so I can't say with any certainty.

Comment: Ok, UIDs are generated by a script in my company, values are always above 50000000. Does it mean I cannot enable user namespaces in docker with these UID's? I tried setting /etc/subuid range to values greater than 50000000 than the default 65536, it works but I am not sure whether this will result in other issues.

Comment: @Poorna Sounds like a broken script.

Comment: It's intentional and also isn't it valid UID?